# How to create an SF Symbol Properly?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, sf-symbols

I'm trying to put an SF Symbol next to a piece of text that I have, however, I get the error 
`Argument type 'Image' does not conform to expected type '_FormatSpecifiable'`

I am fairly new to Xcode and swift UI so basic explanations would be appreciated.

```
import SwiftUI


struct HaveACodeButton: View {
    var body: some View {

        //NavigationView {

            NavigationLink(destination: CodeLoginPage()) {

                VStack {

                    Spacer()

                    Text("Have a code?")
                        .padding()
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .font(.callout)

                    Text("\(Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "arrow.right.circle")!))")
                }
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.horizontal)


        //}
    }
}

struct HaveACodeButton_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HaveACodeButton()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `Image(systemName: "arrow.right.circle")`.

It's a little odd, but you actually use an `Image` View to create them on iOS.

On macOS you can drag the symbol into the quotes on `Text("")`, but that requires that the user be running Catalina (and I'm not sure if it's the recommended way).

Comment: Awesome, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because `Text` Does not have an initializer that accepts another View..

If you want to place an image under the 'Have a Code?' `Text` view, then you can change your `VStack` to the following:

```
VStack {
    Spacer()

    Text("Have a code?")
        .padding()
        .foregroundColor(.blue)
        .font(.callout)

    Image(systemName: "arrow.right.circle")
}
```

Otherwise, if you want to place the Image to the right of the 'Have a Code?' `Text` view change `VStack` above to an `HStack`.